# Firefox Addon. How to determine is the element of the array a file or a directory?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to get a list of files and directories in Firefox Add-ons.

```
var io_file = require("sdk/io/file");
var HomePath = require('sdk/system').pathFor("Home");

var list_files = io_file.list(HomePath);
```

How to determine is the element of the array a file or a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");

let path = "/Users/Work/";
let list = fileIO.list(path);

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  let item = fileIO.join(path, list[i]);
  if (fileIO.isFile(item)) {
    console.log(item + " is a file");
  }
  else {
    console.log(item + " is a directory");
  }
}
```

or

```
    const {Cu} = require("chrome");
    const {TextEncoder, OS} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});

    var iterator = new OS.File.DirectoryIterator('/home/user');
    var promise = iterator.forEach(
        function onEntry(entry) {
            if (entry.isDir) { // is Directory
                console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
            } else { // is File
                console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
            }
        }
    );
    promise.then(
        function onSuccess() {
            iterator.close();
            return subdirs;
        },
        function onFailure(reason) {
            iterator.close();
            throw reason;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `console.log('debug:', list_files)` and then press Ctrl + Shift + J and then click on the link next to list_files, then it opens in varaible viewer and you can explore it there.

like this, notice the "Browser Console" box and see the "Properties" section below, tha comes up when I clicked on "[object MouseEvent]"s you see in the logs above.
[image: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/my20code20works_zpsdd244f45.png]

Comment: There's just an array of values ​​that indicate a directory?

Comment: Now open each one of the items in the array and look for something that indicates dir or not. So like open one item that is a known directory, and one that you know is not a directory, then compare the properties.

Comment: There are no properties in the result array. That compare?

Comment: Can you upload your addon to github ill take a look, please make your addon do console.log of the list so i can just install and look at variable viewer in browser console for you and report back.

Comment: can you upload the xpi please, i dont know a lick of addon sdk installation :( i tried finding an addon sdk addon in repos so i can just swithc out the main.js for your code but failed :(